# Is there best practice on how to highlight the new post after redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, redirect, highlight

I wanna hightlight the changed or new post after i redirect_to the show page.
I know i can use the flash to make a flag for that.but,it sounds not the rails way.
any thought?

Answer (score 1):

You can send additional parameters with redirect_to:

```
redirect_to item, :highlight_post => new_or_changed_post
```

Comment: i think the highlight_post is in the url query string,right? but i will highlight twice when user push refresh.